# error adding parameters to sql command in VB quickfix

Tags: vb.net

i tried passing the parameter pdata which needs to b a varchar from a textbox  and get the error :

```
Method not found: 'Void System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Rollback(System.String)'.
```

heres my code :

```
Protected Sub changeNum_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles changeNum.Click

    Dim retValue As Integer
    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    connection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=151-rsS\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=easyDb;Integrated Security=SSPI; ")
    Dim Command = New SqlCommand("UPDATE mytable Set pdata = @value1", connection)

    Command.Parameters.AddwithValue("@value1", htgtextbox.Text)
    connection.Open()
    retValue = Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connection.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Your reason is you are trying to use `SqlConnection & SqlCommand` which will not work for the version you are targeting... You are using SqlExpress and you can't use the one's I mention above... You need to look at `sqlcecommand` and `sqlceconnection`... The `ce` is for Compact Edition

Comment: its the addwith value line that throws it

Comment: @codexer how do i go about changing it over?

Comment: Change what class you are targeting for your command and connections.

Comment: You need to import `System.Data.SqlServerCe` to use it... Also I have answered similar question **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390748/setting-up-sqlconnection-string-in-vb-net-for-a-local-database-created-through-v/21390898#21390898** there...

Comment: @Codexer - i don't think SqlExpress is the same thing as CE.  I have used both `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` with SQL Express in the past.

Comment: @bigdowg - Have you tried stepping through the code?  The error message you posted doesn't make sense in connection with `AddWithValue`.

Comment: Try to remove  @: Command.Parameters.AddwithValue("value1", htgtextbox.Text)

Comment: @bigdowg wow, just noticed a type-o in your `AddwithValue` method... It should **not be: AddwithValue**. It should be `AddWithValue`. Notice the lowercase "with", it should be uppercase. This may be the culprit as this isn't a valid method for this class...